# RewriteCond works on HTTP but not on HTTPS virtual host

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, pdf.js

i want to rewrite all URLs with trailing ".pdf" to open the pdf-files in the mozilla.pdf.js and have successfully testet following RewriteRule and RewriteCond on my HTTP virtual host (I use apache2 on ubuntu server btw):

example URL to rewrite:

```
http://server-test.local/downloads/dir2/file5/test.pdf
```

example target URL after rewrite:

```
http://server-test.local/libs/mozilla.pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file=/downloads/dir2/file5/test.pdf
```

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !viewer.html
RewriteRule ^(.+)(\.pdf)$ http://server-test.local/libs/mozilla.pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file=$1 [R=301,L]
```

So the `RewriteCond` prevents another redirect which will cause the `mozilla.pdf.js` to try to load itself instead of the PDF file and cause an error. (Sry if description is unclear, i am not really into this topic)

Now I've tried to apply exact the same RewriteCond and RewriteRule for my other virtual host (https), which is - except of SSL and a Kerberos implementation - exact the same as the "server-test" virtual host:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !viewer.html
RewriteRule ^(.+)(\.pdf)$ https://server-prod.local/libs/mozilla.pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file=$1 [R=301,L]
```

but it seems that somehow the `RewriteCond` does not apply. The result is, that the redirect to the `mozilla.pdf.js` works, but the PDF will not be rendered and an error of the `mozilla.pdf.js` appears ("invalid PDF structure"), because - this is my theory- there is another redirection, so the `mozilla.pdf.js` does not load/render the pdf but it tries to load its own `viewer.html` instead.

I have also tried the following `RewriteCond`s, but no one of them changed the behaviour:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !viewer.html*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/libs/mozilla.pdf.js/web/viewer.html*
RewriteCond !viewer.html
```

My aim with these `RewriteCond`s is to prevent another (loop) redirection, if the URL before rewrite containing the string "viewer.html", so if the `[...]/viewer.html?file=/downloads/dir2/file5/test.pdf` is the `REQUEST_URI`, no more rewrite should happen.

Can someone please explain to me, why the `RewriteCond` works on the test virtual host (HTTP) but not on the production virtual host (HTTPS)? Except the SSL and the fact that the SSL secured virtual host has a Kerberos implementation, both virtual hosts, their directories and their configs are mostly the same. Is the SSL the problem? And does anyone know how I can fix this issue on the SSL virtual host? I need to find a solution somehow...

I would appreciate every kind of hints/help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> example target URL after rewrite: `http://example.com/libs/mozilla.pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file=/downloads/dir2/file5/test.pdf`

However, your directive does not currently do this. It *redirects* (not "rewrites") to `http://example.com/libs/mozilla.pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file=downloads/dir2/file5/test` - note the missing slash at the start of the `file` URL parameter value and the missing file extension.

This might be working on one server and not the other if MultiViews is enabled on the former. (This effectively enables extensionless URLs to "work".)

To correct the `RewriteRule` directive:

```
RewriteRule \.pdf$ https://example.com/libs/mozilla.pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file=%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The `file` URL parameter will now contain `/downloads/dir2/file5/test.pdf`.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing. However, should this be a 301 (permanent) redirect? You mention "rewrite" in your question and you have tagged the question `url-rewriting` - which this is not. Are you wanting the user to be physically redirected to this new URL? It looks like this should really be an *internal rewrite* (ie. not exposing `mozilla.pdf.js`)? In which case, this should be rewritten like the following:

```
RewriteRule \.pdf$ /libs/mozilla.pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

> an error of the mozilla.pdf.js appears ("invalid PDF structure"), because -thats my theory- there is another redirection, so the mozilla.pdf.js does not load/render the pdf but it tries to load its own viewer.html instead.

Although if that is the case then it would result in a redirect-loop, but the error you are seeing is not indicative of that.

Also, have you confirmed that the `Referer` HTTP request header is being sent by the browser for this request and is set as expected? The problem here is that the `Referer` is *unreliable*. It can be suppressed by the browser for several reasons.

A better approach would be if `mozilla.pdf.js` set a custom header as part of the request and this could be reliably checked in the mod_rewrite *condition*.

Alternatively, make the URL-path different from the actual filesystem path. (Although the actual files could be requested if the file-path became known.)

---

*Aside:*

> So the `RewriteCond` prevents another redirect which will cause the `mozilla.pdf.js` to try to load itself instead of the PDF file and cause an error.

It won't try to load "itself". The `RewriteRule` pattern would already prevent that from happening since it only matches `.pdf` files (although that isn't what's happening here). The check against the `Referer` is an attempt to prevent a recursive loop... to prevent `viewer.html` being repeatedly called and passing the same `.pdf` file in the `file` URL parameter.

I'm assuming `mozilla.pdf.js` makes an HTTP request for the PDF file passed in the `file` URL parameter. The "problem" (in the case of an external redirect) is to differentiate between a direct request from the user and a request from the *script* (both are client requests from the browser).

Comment: Thank you for the hints. I have tried both solutions you gave to me. I also checked if the referer was given in the header and yes, I was able to find the right referer in the header. I also compared the loaded files in the developer-tools in MS Edge. The difference: on the working virtualHost, the last loaded file showing in the network tab is the "test.pdf". On the non working one, the last file showing in the network tab ist the viewer.html?file=[...]. I also noticed, that in the answer header of the test.pdf, the given content type is text/html and not application/pdf as I've expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think, I was able to fix my issue, by additionally adding

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !file=`

to my RewriteConds of my RewriteRule. Now the mozilla.pdf.js opens and show me the PDF file.
@MrWhite Thx again for your explanation.